# Creating multiple y-axis on both sides

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to create a graph that has multiple y-axis on both left and right side.

The code below produces a graph with multiple y axis on the right side. I've tried changing the rspline setting to 'left', but it doesn't work.

How do I add y4 on the left side?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rcParams
%matplotlib inline
x = np.random.rand(20)
y1 = x*5
y2 = x*5 + 0.2
y3 = x*x*3.5 + 0.2*x
y4 = x*5 + 0.2*x
yLimMin = 0
yLimMax = 2.1
lineWidth = 1.0
fontSize = 24
subTitle = ""

plt.rcParams.update({'axes.labelsize': 'small'})
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(21,29.7))
ax11 = fig.add_subplot(411)

subplotAdjustRight = 0.90
mks = 19 # marker step
ax11.plot(x,y1, linestyle='-', linewidth=lineWidth, color = 'k',
          marker='*', markevery=11*mks, 
          label="CO")
ax11.set_ylabel('CO [%]', color='k')
plt.ylim((0,5))
fig.suptitle(subTitle, fontsize = fontSize)
ax11.yaxis.grid()
plt.locator_params(axis='y', nbins=10)
ax12=ax11.twinx()
ax12.plot(x,y2,linestyle='-', linewidth=lineWidth, color='r',
          marker='*', markevery=11*mks, 
          label="CO22")
ax12.set_ylabel('NO [%]', color='r')
plt.ylim((0,10))
plt.locator_params(axis='y', nbins=10)

ax13= ax11.twinx()
rspine = ax13.spines['right']
rspine.set_position(('axes', 1.05))
ax13.set_frame_on(True)
ax13.plot(x,y3,linestyle='-', linewidth=lineWidth, color='m',
          marker='*', markevery=11*mks, 
          label="CO222")
ax13.set_ylabel('O [%] ', color='m')
plt.ylim((0,20))
plt.locator_params(axis='y', nbins=10)
```

[image: results]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logic is always the same. You create a twin axes and offset the spine. The only difference when creating an axes which should appear at the left side of the plot is that you need to tell matplotlib to set the ticks and the ticklabel to the left (because by default a twin axes has them set to the right).

```
ax14= ax11.twinx()
ax14.yaxis.tick_left()
rspine = ax14.spines['left']
rspine.set_position(('axes', -0.15))
ax14.set_ylabel('blubb ', color='limegreen')
ax14.yaxis.set_label_position("left")
```

[image]